# What is “python -c import pty;pty.spawn(”bash“) ” doing?

Tags: bash, python

There's a process running on a server  I'm using, and lots of people have access to.

When I do top I see it taking up ~99% of the CPU.

with `ps aux` I can see that the command in question is:

```
python -c import pty;pty.spawn("bash")
```

I read the docs and they say

> pty.spawn(argv[, master_read[, stdin_read]])
>
> Spawn a process, and connect its controlling terminal with the current process’s standard io. This is often used to baffle programs which insist on reading from the controlling terminal.
>
> The functions master_read and stdin_read should be functions which read from a file descriptor. The defaults try to read 1024 bytes each time they are called.

But I don't understand why someone would do this. Why would someone use a shell to invoke python to spawn a shell? And why is it taking up so much CPU?

Am I missing something or do I need a coffee?

Basically I want to know what this process is actually 'doing' with 99% of the CPU, so I can decide whether to kill it or not (remember, not just me on the box).

A sys-admin I am not. I'm one of 'those' developers  who just knows enough to get by.

I'm not really sure how to dig further into this - any ideas?

Edit: Is an exploit the only use of this type of command? Again, lots of people have access to this box. Could it not have a legit purpose? Any way I can differentiate one from the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: @DeerHunter is an exploit the only reson you can think of for a command like this? Any idea how I could dig deeper one way or another?

Comment: Paul, please ask your sysadmin or your security specialist to investigate. It could mean hundreds of different things. One way to look into it is by running `lsof` and checking what files this process keeps open. Anyhow, don't do it on your own.